# "Shortcut to" or "shortcut for"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Which of these sentences would be correct, or are they both correct?

"A shortcut to finding the inverse of a 2x2 matrix is..."

"A shortcut for finding the inverse of a 2x2 matrix is..."

Comment: They're both fine.

Comment: Both are correct, I think, but I would contend that "for" might be preferable in that context.   The way I read it, "a shortcut to" implies the destination is the object; whereas "a shortcut for" implies the process itself is the object of the short-cutting.  For example, a shortcut TO Grandmother's house (destination) might be to just go over the river, but a shortcut FOR making a pie (process) might include buying a pre-made crust.  I guess it depends on what comes after the ellipsis, but "finding the inverse of a 2x2 matrix" seems to better describe a process rather than a destination.

Answer (score 1):

This Google Ngram supports other answers and comments which state that both are correct, but *shortcut to* is **generally** used more often than *shortcut for*:

[image: Google ngram]

However, note that this chart doesn't distinguish between a process and a destination; it also doesn't distinguish between *to* as a preposition and *to* as an infinitive marker. Aside from these two examples, there is a third option to convey the same meaning, using to-infinitive instead of the -ing form:

> A shortcut to find the inverse of 2x2 matrix...

The chart above doesn't distinguish between *shortcut to find* and *shortcut to finding*.

Of these three options, Google Ngram chart indicates that *shortcut to finding* is the most often used one:

[image: Google Ngram2]

I've searched through half a dozen of dictionaries, and none of them listed an example with *for*. This may or may not mean that they prefer constructions with *to* (the space for examples is limited and they can't cover all possibilities). It definitely doesn't mark the missing option as incorrect.

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/shortcut) lists these examples:

> I used a shortcut to calculate the total weight.
>
> There are no shortcuts to learning another language.

Answer (score 0):

The normal and logic preposition is "to".
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shortcut?q=shortcut

Comment: Your link merely shows an example of "shortcut to".  It does not say that "to" is the only proper preposition to be used.  Both "to" and "for" are correct in this context with no discernible difference in meaning.

Comment: If one preposition is the preferred one that does not exclude the possibility  that other prepostions can be  used. And I admit that for + destination is frequently used and  I can imagine that a lot of people say "a shortcut for". In this respect dictionaries are not too exact. Often they  show no preposition at all or only the preferred one. Sometimes you can find two concurring prepositions, but not very often. Dictionaries can never register everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think *to* tends to be preferred because it's consistent with the original meaning of the word *shortcut*. This originally only applied to travelling, and you took a shortcut to get to some destination. It has since been expanded metaphorically to mant things that make a process easier or quicker, but we still use the original preposition.

Where I usually see *for* preferred is in discussion of computer interfaces, where you have one thing that stands in for something else that's harder to access. In that case, you say that thing X is a shortcut *for* thing Y.